# New graphics card, no display

Tags: graphics-card, display, power-supply, gpu, computer-building

I put together a new build, and the new graphics card I purchased is not displaying anything on my monitors (meaning, my monitors are not detecting anything). Here are my build list, some facts about my build and what I have done, in an attempt to resolve.

[Build list](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/vztyLJ)

Facts: my CPU is not an APU, my motherboard has no on-board graphics, all hardware/software *should* be compatible together (I am 99.9% sure, unless I am missing something), the previous GPU was an EVGA 1060 (which works with my new build, that's how I am typing this). My graphics card is using an 8 pin for power and a 6 pin for fans. From the GPU, the 8 pin goes to an 8 pin to 6 pin/6pin splitter, then 6pin/6pin to 8pin, into my PSU. The 6pin that comes from the GPU fans goes to one molex, then molex to 6 pin, to my PSU. (hope that last part isn't confusing)

What I have done in an attempt to resolve:

- BIOS is up-to-date
- verified that PCIe slots are enabled in BIOS
- cleared all previous graphics drivers with ddu (not in safe more though, should that really matter?)
- quadruple verified that cables are sat in the correct slots/inputs.
- reset all cables
- reset all hardware into motherboard
- reset the CMOS battery
- tried all PCIe slots
- tried 3 different monitors
- tried DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort, DVI to VGA, and different cables of the same format

I thank you greatly for reading this, if anyone does. I posted this here, because you all are impressive 'answer-ers.' I apologize for any typos or nonsense. I will gladly clarify if needed.

Comment: 1) When you computer powers up it should display something on the screen. There is no need to worry about software at this point. You power up, the UEFI firmware (which you called BIOS) run and output should appear on a monitor. No need to worry about drivers at this stage.  2) Even with the wrong drivers windows is likely to just boot, briefly go low res and then automatically update the drivers. (which my recent win10 GTX970 -> 1080 upgrade did flawlessless to me surprise). I expect the same in your case unless you run XP or older.

Comment: 2) No image at all usually means broken hardware, or not enough power. Or something not connected.  I guess you already did it but make sure all connectors connect properly.

Comment: 3) Lastly, the connector flow between the graphics card and the PSU is sadly unclear to me. I added my understanding of it here ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxSZG.png ) but unless you had to short cables and made do with what you had I probably got it wrong (since two cables directly from the PSU to the graphics card would have suffised).

Comment: 1) @hennes Okay, thanks for clearing that up. I was pretty sure drivers had nothing to do with the motherboard, and just Windows 10 Pro- but I was just so confused why it was not being detected by the monitor at all. I will forget drivers/software then.

2) My build only uses, at max 400w, and I have a 550w power supply. Do I need more wattage wiggle room?

3) I corrected the flow of your image, I am using an 8 pin psu input for my gpu. Thanks for creating that for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. My 550w power supply unit was either faulty, not putting out enough wattage or one of my cabling methods wasn't holding up properly. I swapped all of my cables with new cables and put in a new 750w power supply unit and my graphics card displays now.